# Displaying all combinations of indexes on pandas then sum

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a 4 indexes Dataframe and I'd like to know how can I make sure that all combinations of indexes are displayed.

I'm running this to sum :

```
df.sum(level=[0,1,2,3]).unstack(fill_value=0).stack()
```

But its only displaying all possible values of the fourth index for each one of the third one. I'd like this to work also for the first and second indexes (filling empty rows with 0).

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a sample of df you are working on and the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
s=df.sum(level=[0,1,2,3])
idx=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([s.index.get_level_values(0).unique(),s.index.get_level_values(1).unique(),s.index.get_level_values(2).unique(),s.index.get_level_values(3).unique()])

s.reindex(idx)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to categories before you perform a `groupby`, then use `fillna`.

By design, grouping by a MultiIndex of categorical columns yields their Cartesian product.

Below is a small example.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.randint(0, 2, 5),
                   'B': np.random.randint(0, 2, 5),
                   'C': np.random.randint(0, 2, 5),
                   'D': np.random.randint(0, 2, 5),
                   'E': np.random.rand(5)})

for col in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']:
    df[col] = df[col].astype('category')

res = df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']).sum().fillna(0)
```

**Result**

```
                E
A B C D          
0 0 0 0  0.982165
      1  0.000000
    1 0  0.000000
      1  0.000000
  1 0 0  0.000000
      1  0.366428
    1 0  0.000000
      1  0.000000
1 0 0 0  0.000000
      1  0.606826
    1 0  0.000000
      1  0.164896
  1 0 0  0.000000
      1  0.000000
    1 0  0.027386
      1  0.000000
```